# - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath is not being called

Tags: ios, uitableview

So its really weird... I have a ViewController called ListEventsViewController

in the header file:

```
@interface ListEventsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *eventsTable;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *events;

@end
```

In the Implementation I am calling the pretty much mandatory functions below:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [events count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [eventsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"eventCell"];

    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"eventCell"];
    }

    NSString *textLabelTitle = [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *textLabelDetail = [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];
    //cell.imageView.image = someimage;
    NSLog(@"Text Label Title: %@", textLabelTitle);
    NSLog(@"Text Label Detail: %@", textLabelDetail);
    cell.textLabel.text = textLabelTitle;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = textLabelDetail;

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is the function - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ is not being called so the cells arent being populated. also the number of cells isnt being allocated either. What could be causing this?

It looks wired up to me heres a picture of the h and IB. [image]

Comment: Are you sure you've connected the delegate property in IB or programmatically?

Comment: IB. Looks connected to me. Added a picture so you can check just incase :).

Comment: As @Rickay said, your IB picture shows that you have not connected to datasource and delegate of your eventsTable to your ListEventsViewController.

Comment: Ohhh of course you have to connect the datasource too! Well.... That worked... Im getting there ;). Cheers guys +! fo both of you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You illustrated in your screenshot that you have linked the table to its IBOutlet, but you haven't linked the table view's delegate or datasource to your controller and therefore your tables delegate methods such as `cellForRowAtIndex` will not be called. Linking these should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have this & this must b your solution

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
         mysampleimage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,3, 40, 40)];
         mysampleimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
         mysampleimage.tag=13;
         [cell.contentView addSubview:mysampleimage];

         myButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         myButton.frame = CGRectMake(165, 10, 65, 30.);
         [myButton setTitle:@"Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         myButton.tag = 14;
         [cell addSubview:myButton];

         lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 6, 200, 43)];
         lbl.tag=12;
         [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
     }
     else
     {
         lbl=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:12];
         mysampleimage=(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:13];
         myButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:14];
     }

     myButton.accessibilityLabel = lbl.text;

     [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myShow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     return cell;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following lines in your coding:

```
tableview.delegate = self;
tableview.datasource = self;
```

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was to comment out 
numberofsectionsintableview