# UITableView updater function not being called ( (UITableview) tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath )

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**EDIT: By "function" I am referring to the (UITableView)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath, it's stated in my title but I wanted to make it clear**

So, yes, there are other answers I have a couple [1stexample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291038/uitableviewcell-tableviewuitableview-tableview-cellforrowatindexpathn), [2ndexample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794262/uitableview-cellforrowatindexpath-is-not-being-called) . My function is not being called for some reason. I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMm5t4APGMM). Went back 5 different times to make sure I did all the datasource and delegates right, I think I am. I have done iOS apps before and never had an issue with this. I don't think anything is wrong with the code, I debugged it and it should be working fine. I'll post it anyways just in case I am making an amateur mistake somewhere in there. Don't think I am, but I've been wrong before.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *array;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self twitterTimeline];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_array count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellID = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    NSDictionary *tweet = _array[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = tweet[@"text"];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

-(void)twitterTimeline
{
    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){


        if(granted == YES)
        {
            NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            if([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) {
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject]; //grabs last account that is on iPhone, perhaps we would have the user make a selection of which user but for this beginning its fine

                NSURL *requestAPI = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.tiwtter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];

                NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                [parameters setObject:@"100"
                    forKey:@"count"];
                [parameters setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];

                SLRequest *posts = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestAPI parameters:parameters];

                posts.account = twitterAccount;

                [posts performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *response, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

                    self.array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                    if(self.array.count != 0) {

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                            [self.tableView reloadData];

                        });
                    }


                }];

            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Here's my referencing outlets (which is why I think it's really weird it's not calling the function). [ScreenshotLink](http://s16.postimg.org/50pcl3e91/i_OS.png). Sorry I guess I need 10 rep to post pictures directly on SO.

I very much appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a breakpoint on `[self.tableView reloadData];`. If your breakpoint never gets hit then your array is empty. You should also check the error value if it has anything useful in it.

Comment: yeah it's not hitting it. I need to go back and make sure I'm doing everything right. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a NSLog in the

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"array count is %d", [_array count]); 
    return [_array count];
}
```

I think it's empty and will therefore not call the other methods.

Comment: yeah found out my array is 0 for some reason. thanks for the tip.